# Sharepoint 2013 - Open with Explorer Issue in Window 2012 Standard server - IE 10/IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

Issue with Sharepoint 2013 when clicking on the "Open with Explorer".

where - Window server 2012 Standard.
using - IE 10 and then standalone IE 11

After window authentication, I am able to access the Sharepoint site. but when I go to Library tab and then click on "Open with Explorer", two time authentication pop up windows comes up. After entering the same username and password. I get the below error message.

Issue:
Error message:
We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add this web site to your Trusted Sites list and try again.

Action Tried:

- Added all the sharepoint site to the Trusted list of Site.
- Restarted the browser.
- Restarting WebClient service
  The WebClient is running and restarting it does not solve the issue.
- installing IE 11.
  Tried to install standalone IE11 from Microsoft site. After rebooting the server. the result is still the same.
  https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4492872
- Desktop Experiences enabled  as per (https://camerondwyer.com/2014/11/12/how-to-installenable-the-webclient-webdav-service-on-windows-server-2012-to-openedit-sharepoint-files/)
- Restarted the server.

Kindly let me know what is missing to get this error fixed.

Update1:
I am seeing this in eventviewer... any idea?

[image]

Comment: You can check **What can go wrong with Open with Explorer** in [this doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-or-move-library-files-by-using-open-with-explorer-aaee7bfb-e2a1-42ee-8fc0-bcc0754f04d2). Besides, you can clear all cache and cookies in IE and test again. I also found [a similar issue](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2294547-sharepoint-2013-open-in-explorer-not-works) and you can refer to.

Comment: @Yu, thanks for the suggestion.... I have gone through them... but it might be different. See the attached image.